# Selecting html elements text as input for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web3js

```
var unixtime =356674566

var newDate = new Date();

newDate.setTime(unixtime * 1000);

dateString = newDate.toUTCString();

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = dateString;
```

I wanted to give `h1` element text(not input text) as an input to var unix timestamp..is there any way to do that?

Comment: Can you provide some HTML code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the `h1` element an `id` and use `document.getElementById` to get the `h1` element. Then you can use `.textContent` to get the text within the `h1` tag. Finally, you can use a `+` to convert the string retrieved from textContent to a number.

See working example below:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var unixtime = +document.getElementById('unix').textContent;
  var newDate = new Date();

  newDate.setTime(unixtime * 1000);
  dateString = newDate.toUTCString();

  document.getElementById("time").textContent = dateString;
});
```

```html
<h1 id="unix">356674566</h1>
<p>Date: <span id="time"></span></p>
```

Comment: @SalmanDev try my updated version. I added an event lister to the script so that it only fires when the page contents have loaded.